# Is there a way to automatically fix `import type` errors on TypeScript when using "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"?

Tags: typescript, eslint, tsc, type-only-import-export

I have a big TypeScript project that I started without using the [`"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#importsNotUsedAsValues) compiler flag. As the project grew, I decided it is a good idea in terms of optimization to enforce `import type` when an import is not being used as a value.

Enabling this works fine and even makes my IDE auto import types using `import types` when possible, and it can also automatically fix open files that do not import types as types only, but not the entire project in one go, and I have so many of those cases in the project that fixing them manually is inconceivable.

I've been reading ESLint, TSC and similar tools documentations trying to find a way I could use them to automatically fix the imports, but with no success. Does anyone know a tool that could automatically fix those issues?

Comment: Notice: `importsNotUsedAsValues` and `preserveValueImports` are deprecated in favor of `verbatimModuleSyntax` since TypeScript 5.0 to simplify three flags (including `isolatedModules `) into one.

Answer (score 48):

After a little more searching, I found ESLint rule [`consistent-type-imports`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports/) which basically ensure the same as `"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"` TypeScript compiler flag but on ESLint level.

Enabling it was as simple as adding

```
'@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': 'error',
```

to `rules` section in my ESLint configuration file.

To autofix, now I then simply needed to run

```
eslint --fix .
```